# R Shiny: How to use a UI textinput from ui, in the server section for subsetting a data frame?

Tags: shiny, subset, reactive

I have not seen this questions clearly answered elsewhere. I would like to have a "textInput" box where a user enters a country name "Argentina". Based on that input, in the server section of the code, I would like to subset a preloaded dataframe by that country name.

Could someone kindly assist me in how one could do this? Many thanks.

Below is a code using mtcars as sample data.

```
# Some Sample data to run app using mtcars
mtcars$Primary<- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$Area <- "Argentina"
mtcars$Y2016<- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$Element <- "Gross Production Value (constant 2004-2006 million US$)"


# Defining UI ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

          # App title ----
          headerPanel("Subsector Selection Tool"),

          # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
          sidebarPanel(

            # Input: Country name
            textInput("country", "Please enter country name", "")#,

          ),

          # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
          mainPanel("")
)



# Use user input (country name) to subset desired dataframe. 
server <- function(input, output) {

#Trying to make user inputed country name into an object to be used in "reactive" code below, which in turn is be used to make dataset for graphing
country_interest <- reactive({
paste(input$country)
})


#Here I am trying to make the data analysis code run and create desired dataset for graphing, and 
subsetting for country selected by user
Value_c_e_PRIM_x  <- reactiveValue({

Value_c <- Value[which(Value$Area==country_interest),]

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example of an app that does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$country <- rep(c("Argentina", "Chile"), 16)

ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("country", "Please enter country name", ""),
  tableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   data <- reactive(mtcars %>% filter(country == input$country))

   output$table <- renderTable({
   data()
   })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, lookout for:

- In your case, it is better to put the filtering options in a `selectInput()`, since there you can put the values that already exist on your dataframe.
- I find it best to put reactive dataframes inside a `reactive` function (as in my example): inside you make all necessary modifications from the inputs, then you just call this object inside the render function (note the parenthesis at the end, since is now a reactive shiny object).

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is incredibly helpful, and has helped me get on my way. Much appreciated